# Removing item from ArrayList using remove(<index>) or remove(<objectRef>)

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to create a program which displays current staff in the `ArrayList` before asking the user for input of a payroll number they'd like to remove. User then should input the payroll number of one of the three staff members and press enter. Upon pressing enter, the program should remove that particular staff member from the array list and display the entire list again (missing out the staff member they've deleted obviously). If the user no longer wishes to remove any payroll numbers, the payroll number entry should be 0 and should then display the contents of the list again.

The problem I'm having is with the remove part.

I've been recommended of two ways of achieving this:

*This 'search' method should return either the position within the ArrayList (so that `remove(<index>)` may be used) or a reference to the object (so that `remove(<objectRef>)` may be used). If the staff member is not found, then the search method should return -1 (if `remove(<index>)` is being used) or null (if `remove(<objectRef>)` is being used).*

However I am not sure how to implement this in Java.

Here is my file structure:

**ArrayListTest.java**

```
import java.util.*;

import personnelPackage.Personnel;

public class ArrayListTest
{
    static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        long searchQuery;

        ArrayList<Personnel> staffList = new ArrayList<Personnel>();
        Personnel[] staff =
            {new Personnel(123456,"Smith","John"),
             new Personnel(234567,"Jones","Sally Ann"),
             new Personnel(999999,"Black","James Paul")};

        for (Personnel person:staff)
            staffList.add(person);

        do
        {
            showDisplay(staffList);

            System.out.print("\nPlease enter a payroll number to search: ");
            searchQuery = keyboard.nextLong();

            searchForPayrollNumber(staffList, searchQuery);


        }while(!(searchQuery == 0));


    }

    private static void showDisplay(ArrayList<Personnel> staffList)
    {
        System.out.print("\n------------- CURRENT STAFF LIST -------------\n");
        for (Personnel person : staffList)
        {
            System.out.println("Payroll number: " + person.getPayNum());
            System.out.println("Surname: " + person.getSurname());
            System.out.println("First name(s): " + person.getFirstNames() + "\n");
        }
    }

    public static void searchForPayrollNumber(ArrayList<Personnel> staffList, long searchQuery)
    {
        long index = staffList.indexOf(searchQuery);;

        for (Personnel person: staffList)
        {
            if (person.getPayNum() == searchQuery)
            {               
                System.out.print("\n------------- Staff member found and removed! -------------");
                System.out.println("\n\nFirst Name(s): " + person.getFirstNames());
                System.out.println("\nSurname: " + person.getSurname());
                System.out.print("\n-----------------------------------------------");

                staffList.remove(index);
                return;
            }
        }

        System.out.print("\n------------- No staff members found. Program terminated -------------");
        return;

    }

}
```

**Personnel.java** (in its own package named personnelPackage)

```
package personnelPackage;

public class Personnel
{
    private long payrollNum;
    private String surname;
    private String firstNames;

    public Personnel(long payrollNum, String surname, String firstNames)
    {
        this.payrollNum = payrollNum;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.firstNames = firstNames;
    }

    public long getPayNum()
    {
        return payrollNum;
    }

    public String getSurname()
    {
        return surname;
    }

    public String getFirstNames()
    {
        return firstNames;
    }

    public void setSurname(String newName)
    {
        surname = newName;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't remove from the list within an enhanced for loop

Comment: How does "staffList.indexOf(searchQuery);" work when searchQuery is long and staffList is ArrayList<Personnel>?

Comment: @ShireResident It's because of the `getPayNum()` method from the `Personnel.java` file/ Personnel class.

Comment: @Olehi - it'll return - 1, though because you are comparing two different types. A long vs the Personnel class, which you didn't implement an equals method or a hashcode method, so I don't think indexOf would work correctly if you did use the right types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static long searchForPayrollNumber(ArrayList<Personnel> staffList, long searchQuery) {
    //long index = staffList.indexOf(searchQuery);

for(int i = 0; i < staffList.size(); i++) {
    if (staffList.get(i).getPayNum() == searchQuery) {
        System.out.print("\n------------- Staff member found and removed! -------------");
        System.out.println("\n\nFirst Name(s): " + staffList.get(i).getFirstNames());
        System.out.println("\nSurname: " + staffList.get(i).getSurname());
        System.out.print("\n-----------------------------------------------");

        //staffList.remove(i);
        return i;
    }
}
System.out.print("\n------------- No staff members found. Program terminated -------------");
return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Consider using [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) for search and removal:

```
Iterator<Personnel> i = staffList.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
    Personnel p = i.next();
    if (p.getPayNum() == searchQuery) {
        // print message
        i.remove();
        return p;
    } 
}
return null;
```

If using `List#remove()` is strictly required, return found personnel `p` and call `if (p != null) staffList.remove(p)`:

```
public static Personnel searchByPayNum(List<Personnel> ps, long num) {
    for (Personnel p : ps) {
        if (p.getPayNum() == num)
            return p;
    }
    return null;
}
```

And in caller code:

```
Personnel p = searchByPayNum(staffList, query);
if (p != null) {
    // log
    staffList.remove(p);
}
```

Comment: I believe the requirement in the question is to simply implement a search method that returns the object or position, not to actually remove from the collection in that same method

Comment: @cricket_007 then things are much more simple, you know

Comment: Sure, but I didn't write the assignment

Comment: Efficiency wise, returning the index is better because you are doing two linear traversals to find the element, then remove it. Also `List#remove` may not work because the equals method isn't implemented on Personnel class

Comment: @cricket_007 1) Agree, better to return index; 2) `equals()` doesn't need to be implemented in this particular case, because object returned from collection is directly passed as `remove()` argument -- here `Object#equals()` will work.

Answer (score 1):

Your search method shouldn't return void. It should return int or long instead,

```
public static long searchForPayrollNumber(ArrayList<Personnel> staffList, long searchQuery)
{
 int index = -1;
 for (int i = 0; i < staffList.size(); i++){
     if(staffList.get(i).getPayNum() == searchQuery){
     index = i;
     System.out.print("\n------------- Found Staff member at position " + index + " in the list");
     break;         
     }
 } 
if (index != -1){
    staffList.remove(index);
    System.out.print("\n------------- Removed the staff member");  
}          
 return index;
}
```

Last approach returned the index. Now when you want to return the object:

```
public static long searchForPayrollNumber(ArrayList<Personnel> staffList, long searchQuery)
{
 Personnel p = null;
 for (int i = 0; i < staffList.size(); i++){
     if(staffList.get(i).getPayNum() == searchQuery){
     p = staffList.get(i);
     break;         
     }
 }          
 staffList.remove(p);     
 return p;
}
```

You must know that after removing it from the list, It will shift any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their indices).

Also, just a suggestion:

Instead of

```
Personnel[] staff =
        {new Personnel(123456,"Smith","John"),
         new Personnel(234567,"Jones","Sally Ann"),
         new Personnel(999999,"Black","James Paul")};
```

Why not

```
staffList.add(new Personnel(123456,"Smith","John"));
staffList.add(new Personnel(234567,"Jones","Sally Ann"));
staffList.add(new Personnel(999999,"Black","James Paul"));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just an advice. Since searching and removing are your primary goals, ArrayList is not the right collection to use.

Create a Hashmap with ID as key and Personnel object as value. This will help in identifying the Personnel in O(1) time and removal as well.

ArrayList should be used only when you know the index to read value. It then does that in O(1). If not, it is O(n) and not as efficient as HashMap.